# Incremental Progress Bar in Windows Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file which scans the computer taking various readings and storing each in to a variable. During this time I would like a little more than a simple message telling the user to 'Please wait - Gathering system information'.

I've tried the quick, easy, (and poor), way of doing this, as follows, as I want this to be a true incremental progress bar.

```batch-file
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Please wait - Gathering system information
echo ----------------------------------
echo Progress: ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0%%
echo ----------------------------------
>nul timeout /t 1 &cls
cls

REM Do something here.

echo.
echo.
echo Please wait - Gathering system information...
echo ----------------------------------
echo Progress: █░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 5%%
echo ----------------------------------
>nul timeout /t 1 &cls
cls

REM Do something else here.

echo.
echo.
echo Please wait - Gathering system information.
echo ----------------------------------
echo Progress: ██░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 10%%
echo ----------------------------------
>nul timeout /t 1 &cls
cls

REM And something else..

echo.
echo.
echo Please wait - Gathering system information..
echo ----------------------------------
echo Progress: ███░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 15%%
echo ----------------------------------
>nul timeout /t 1 &cls
cls

REM Etc...
```

However, the effect is not exactly great, as the `cls` command causes the command window to flicker, and there has to be a 'false' pause after each update, which slows the whole process… Also not great.

I have the following that looks great, but I have no idea how to 'increment' the bar after every section of code, as per my initial example, and having it play from 0-100% before running anything else is a bit pointless.

```batch-file
@echo off &cls
mode con: cols=70 lines=5  &color f0

call :setESC
chcp 65001 >nul

set progress=
set/a progressnum=0

:gettingdata
set progress=%progress%%ESC%[96m█%ESC%[30m
cls
echo.
echo. Please wait - Gathering system information...
echo. %progress% (%progressnum%/20)
ping localhost -n 2 >nul

set/a progressnum=%progressnum% +1
if %progressnum%==20 goto finished

goto gettingdata

:finished
echo.
echo. Finished
echo. %ESC%[92m████████████████████%ESC%[30m (20/20)
echo. Press any key to exit &>nul timeout /t -1 &exit /B


:setESC
REM Define escape char
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set ESC=%%b
  exit /B 0
)
```

So, my question is, how can I get the effect of the second script, but actually increment the bar after each section of my batch script has executed?

Comment: You contradict yourself in your question - you say you want a true progress bar, however you also say you want progress updated after command blocks have executed. Note: Commands and Calls to funtions are blocking, and loops like the one in the second script you've posted are only relevent when a known number of actions are going to be taken if you really want the progress dispaly to be meaningful. If you just want an Aesthetic animation while your script does stuff, consider something like [this](https://pastebin.com/D86xTVZx)

Comment: Thank you for you comment @T3RR0R but I don’t see any contradiction. I would like to update the progress meter after each section of the script has been actioned. At this point it is simply checking for registry keys and/or setting variables - basically gathering information. I simply require a way to up date the progress bar after each of these segments has finished with a user definable amount without using CLS. I see what you are saying after looking at the code you linked to but that’s overkill for what I require. Anon’s seems to fulfil my question but I am yet to test it.

Comment: The contradiction comes from the fact that you stated you want a true progress bar, which these solutions are not.

Comment: Maybe it was down to the terminology used. I know the solutions offered do not offer a true 'progress meter' in Windows batch. However, this is as close as it can be and the answer received by Anon ticks all the boxes for the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out (with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108380/coding-a-real-time-progress-bar-in-batch)).

Below is how I set up and used the script with only small additions to make it work with Unicode symbols.

First, set up your environment however you please. For the purpose of this post we will use the following:

```
@echo off &cls
mode con: cols=70 lines=4  &color f0
setlocal
```

Now in between each segment of your code you'll need to define the percentage of the progress bar by calling `:drawProgressBar` like so:

```
REM Your code here (segment 1)
REM - Progress Bar 0% - 33% ------------------------------------------------------
echo. Please wait - Gathering system information...
    for /l %%f in (0 1 33) do (
        call :drawProgressBar %%f "Code segment 1 finished"
    )
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Repeat as required increasing the percentage each time like so:

```
REM Your code here (segment 2)
REM - Progress Bar 34% - 66% -----------------------------------------------------
    for /l %%f in (34 1 66) do (
        call :drawProgressBar %%f "Code segment 2 finished"
    )
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Your code here (segment 3)
REM - Progress Bar 67% - 100% ----------------------------------------------------
    for /l %%f in (67 1 100) do (
        call :drawProgressBar %%f "Code segment 2 finished"
    )
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM The rest of your script goes here
endlocal
echo. &echo. All done. Press any key to Exit. &>nul timeout /t -1 &exit /B
```

Addendum: If you would like each segment to show 0-100% (as opposed to counting up from 0-100% overall) then you can use the following each time and simply update the description:

```
REM - Progress Bar 0% - 100% -----------------------------------------------------
    for /l %%f in (0 1 100) do (
            call :drawProgressBar %%f "Code segment finished"
        )
REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Ok to continue and this is personal preference here, but I then like to resize the CMD Window with another `cls &mode con: cols=70 lines=60  &color f0` (or whatever size and/or colour you need) then continue to the output. As I say, this is just personal choice but I think it looks better with the progress meter in a smaller windows while the information is gathered before moving on to the 'main output' of the script.

Finally, add the following to the end of your batch file:

```
:drawProgressBar value [text]
if "%~1"=="" goto :eof
if not defined pb.barArea call :initProgressBar
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a "pb.value=%~1 %% 101", "pb.filled=pb.value*pb.barArea/100", "pb.dotted=pb.barArea-pb.filled", "pb.pct=1000+pb.value"
set "pb.pct=%pb.pct:~-3%"
if "%~2"=="" ( set "pb.text=" ) else ( 
    set "pb.text=%~2%pb.back%" 
    set "pb.text=!pb.text:~0,%pb.textArea%!"
)
<nul set /p "pb.prompt= !pb.fill:~0,%pb.filled%!!pb.dots:~0,%pb.dotted%! [%pb.pct%%%] %pb.text%!pb.cr!"
endlocal
goto :eof

:initProgressBar [fillChar] [dotChar]
chcp 65001 >nul
if defined pb.cr call :finalizeProgressBar
for /f %%a in ('copy "%~f0" nul /z') do set "pb.cr=%%a"
if "%~1"=="" ( set "pb.fillChar=▓" ) else ( set "pb.fillChar=%~1" )
if "%~2"=="" ( set "pb.dotChar=▒" ) else ( set "pb.dotChar=%~2" )
set "pb.console.columns="
for /f "tokens=2 skip=4" %%f in ('mode con') do if not defined pb.console.columns set "pb.console.columns=%%f"
set /a "pb.barArea=pb.console.columns/2-2", "pb.textArea=pb.barArea-9"
set "pb.fill="
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%p in (1 1 %pb.barArea%) do set "pb.fill=!pb.fill!%pb.fillChar%"
set "pb.fill=!pb.fill:~0,%pb.barArea%!"
set "pb.dots=!pb.fill:%pb.fillChar%=%pb.dotChar%!"
set "pb.back=!pb.fill:~0,%pb.textArea%!
set "pb.back=!pb.back:%pb.fillChar%= !"
endlocal & set "pb.fill=%pb.fill%" & set "pb.dots=%pb.dots%" & set "pb.back=%pb.back%"
chcp 1252 >nul
goto :eof

:finalizeProgressBar [erase]
if defined pb.cr (
    if not "%~1"=="" (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "pb.back="
        for /l %%p in (1 1 %pb.console.columns%) do set "pb.back=!pb.back! "
        <nul set /p "pb.prompt=!pb.cr!!pb.back:~1!!pb.cr!"
        endlocal
    )
)
for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%v in ('set pb.') do set "%%v="
goto :eof
```

This is probably an easy task for the seasoned guys & gals here but I struggled with how to do this so I thought that I would share what worked for me and how I used the script.

Full credit goes to [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) who is the original author of the script used. Please see the original post for more customisation options.