# Coding two real time progress bars in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I really like the progress bar that @MCND coded in this post - [Coding a real time progress bar in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108380/coding-a-real-time-progress-bar-in-batch/)

Is there any way to add a second real-time progress bar just below the first one which could be manipulated seperately showing the overall progress of the batch file, while the first progress bar shows the real-time progress of the current function?

I tried copying the `:drawProgressBar`, `:initProgressBar` and `:finalizeProgressBar` subroutines and adding a 1 to the end of them and all `pb` variables in the subroutines to create a distinct subroutine, but no luck.

**@MCND 's original post/code:**

Just a skelleton. Adapt as needed.

The basic idea is to output the line with the progress bar with an ending carriage return to return to the start of the line and be able to repaint the next state over the previous one.

All "problematic" code wrapped into subroutines so you only need to call :drawProgressBar percentValue "operationText"

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /l %%f in (0 1 100) do (
        call :drawProgressBar %%f "up test with a long text that will not fit on screen unless you have a lot of space"
    )
    for /l %%f in (100 -1 0) do (
        call :drawProgressBar %%f "going down test"
    )
    for /l %%f in (0 5 100) do (
        call :drawProgressBar !random! "random test"
    )

    rem Clean all after use
    call :finalizeProgressBar 1


    call :initProgressBar "|" " "
    call :drawProgressBar 0 "this is a custom progress bar"
    for /l %%f in (0 1 100) do (
        call :drawProgressBar %%f 
    )

    endlocal
    exit /b


:drawProgressBar value [text]
    if "%~1"=="" goto :eof
    if not defined pb.barArea call :initProgressBar
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set /a "pb.value=%~1 %% 101", "pb.filled=pb.value*pb.barArea/100", "pb.dotted=pb.barArea-pb.filled", "pb.pct=1000+pb.value"
    set "pb.pct=%pb.pct:~-3%"
    if "%~2"=="" ( set "pb.text=" ) else ( 
        set "pb.text=%~2%pb.back%" 
        set "pb.text=!pb.text:~0,%pb.textArea%!"
    )
    <nul set /p "pb.prompt=[!pb.fill:~0,%pb.filled%!!pb.dots:~0,%pb.dotted%!][ %pb.pct% ] %pb.text%!pb.cr!"
    endlocal
    goto :eof

:initProgressBar [fillChar] [dotChar]
    if defined pb.cr call :finalizeProgressBar
    for /f %%a in ('copy "%~f0" nul /z') do set "pb.cr=%%a"
    if "%~1"=="" ( set "pb.fillChar=#" ) else ( set "pb.fillChar=%~1" )
    if "%~2"=="" ( set "pb.dotChar=." ) else ( set "pb.dotChar=%~2" )
    set "pb.console.columns="
    for /f "tokens=2 skip=4" %%f in ('mode con') do if not defined pb.console.columns set "pb.console.columns=%%f"
    set /a "pb.barArea=pb.console.columns/2-2", "pb.textArea=pb.barArea-9"
    set "pb.fill="
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    for /l %%p in (1 1 %pb.barArea%) do set "pb.fill=!pb.fill!%pb.fillChar%"
    set "pb.fill=!pb.fill:~0,%pb.barArea%!"
    set "pb.dots=!pb.fill:%pb.fillChar%=%pb.dotChar%!"
    set "pb.back=!pb.fill:~0,%pb.textArea%!
    set "pb.back=!pb.back:%pb.fillChar%= !"
    endlocal & set "pb.fill=%pb.fill%" & set "pb.dots=%pb.dots%" & set "pb.back=%pb.back%"
    goto :eof

:finalizeProgressBar [erase]
    if defined pb.cr (
        if not "%~1"=="" (
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            set "pb.back="
            for /l %%p in (1 1 %pb.console.columns%) do set "pb.back=!pb.back! "
            <nul set /p "pb.prompt=!pb.cr!!pb.back:~1!!pb.cr!"
            endlocal
        )
    )
    for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%v in ('set pb.') do set "%%v="
    goto :eof
```

Comment: I'm not sure that there is such a thing as a realtime progress bar in a batch file scenario, without running it in a parallel process, and for the exact duration of the task to have first been calculated. Lets say you have one hundred files to copy, after having copied fifty of them, that will not necessarily be fifty percent of progress, because all files will not take the exact same amount of time to copy. Additionally, if you intersperse the progressing commands with a progress bar update, you are then introducing another unknown and variable time element further skewing the visual results.

Comment: You're right Compo I don't think a truly real-time progress bar is possible in a batch file without running in a parallel process as you said. But the code above by @MCND when used interspersed between the processing commands is as close as possible and gives a reasonable idea of the progress of the commands in the batch file, and shows that it hasn't gotten stuck.

Comment: "Here is some code I found. Adapt it to my needs" is not on-topic for this site. Try yourself and tell us where and why you stuck, so we can help you *with your code*.